# Use control flow on async method with node.js and async.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, control-flow

I'm trying to change a working code that doesn't have any control flow to display when everything is done how much change were done. WIthout control flow, it's not possible.

To do so, I'm trying async, but I'm a bit confused here.

Old code:

```
public static populate(){
    // Read all files inside the populate folder.
    fs.readdir(__config.path.populate, function(err, files){
        if(err){
            consoleDev(err);
        }else{
            // For each file, get the data to populate stored in the file.
            _.each(files, function(file){
                _.each(require(__config.path.base + __config.path.populate + file), function(documents){
                    // The file name must be the same as the targeted model.
                    var Model = __Dao.getModel(file.split('.')[0]);// Filter the extension.

                    if(Model){
                        // For each data, try to add it if it does not exist in the DB.
                        Model.findOrCreate(documents, function(err, doc, created){
                            if(created){
                                consoleDev('The following document was created in the [' + Model.modelName + '] collection: ' + JSON.stringify(doc));
                            }
                        });
                    }else{
                        consoleDev('Unable to populate the file: ' + file + '. The model was not found.')
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    });
}
```

New code:

```
public static populate(){
    // Read all files inside the populate folder.
    fs.readdir(__config.path.populate, function(err, files){
        if(err){
            consoleDev(err);
        }else{
            _.each(files, function(file){
                // Read all files in async mode with control flow.
                async.each(require(__config.path.base + __config.path.populate + file), function(documents, callback){
                    // The file name must be the same as the targeted model.
                    var Model = __Dao.getModel(file.split('.')[0]);// Filter the extension.

                    if(Model){
                        // For each data, try to add it if it does not exist in the DB.
                        Model.findOrCreate(documents, function(err, doc, created){
                            if(created){
                                consoleDev('The following document was created in the [' + Model.modelName + '] collection: ' + JSON.stringify(doc));
                                Populate._added++;
                            }else{
                                Populate._read++;
                            }
                            callback();
                        });
                    }else{
                        callback('Unable to populate the file: ' + file + '. The model was not found.')
                    }
                });
            }, function(err){
                if(err){
                    console.log(err);
                }
                consoleDev(Populate._added + ' documents were added. There are now ' + Populate._read + ' + ' + Populate._added + ' = ' + (Populate._read + Populate._added) + ' documents populated.');
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Nothing is showed on the console at the end and I don't have any error on the console. The script still works and add documents that wasn't present in the DB before. But I still don't have a message saying me how much were added.

I tried to do `async.each(files, function(file, callback){` instead but I get the error `Error: Callback was already called.`.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Note that I use Typescript, that's why everything is written OOP oriented, but that's javascript language.

Comment: This is probably unrelated, but you shouldn't use strings for errors. Make proper Error instances instead: `callback(new Error('Unable to populate the file: ' + file + '. The model was not found.'))`

Comment: You're also missing the callback function after the iterator function for `async.each()`.

Comment: About strings, I actually simplified this example, because I use a custom Message object that deal with i18N and dynamic variables inside the message, manage a status, can contain data and so on, I don't use the native Error class at all but thanks to point this out.